# How to place c2 children to the top and to the bottom of the parent in css?

Tags: css, styles, tailwind-css

I need to add 2 children of a parent element one on the top and another on the bottom. something like this.
[image]

and this is the code I have.

```
 <div class=" w-full flex justify-betwen bg-white items-center">
    <div class="ml-auto">
        <img class="object-cover mr-2 md:mr-4 ml-2 md:ml-4 float-left h-40  lg:w-32 w-14 xs:w-16"
            src="../img/Bless.png" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="w-full mx-8">
        <div class="text-redfull text-ms xs:text-lg md:text-xl lg:text-2xl xl:text-3xl">
            Some text here to top as a title.
        </div>

        <div
            class=" text-gray70 flex justify-between items-center text-xs xs:text-base md:text-base lg:text-lg mb-0">
           and this is the date to the bottom Uploaded Auguts 4, 2020
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

## Title should stay at the top.

## Date to the bottom.

If anyone knows:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add two divs for Title and Date and add vertical margin to them.

I am not sure whether you want with the text or not so I had implemented for both the cases.

Case 1: With text

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="justify-betwen flex w-full items-center bg-white">
  <div class="ml-auto">
    <img class="xs:w-16 float-left mr-2 ml-2 h-40 w-14 object-cover md:mr-4 md:ml-4 lg:w-32" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.s2014.png" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="mx-8 w-full">
    <div class="text-3xl font-semibold text-red-900">Your Title here</div>
    <div class="my-3">
      <div class="text-ms xs:text-lg text-red-500 md:text-xl lg:text-2xl xl:text-3xl">Some text here to top as a title.</div>

      <div class="xs:text-base mb-0 flex items-center justify-between text-xs text-gray-500 md:text-base lg:text-lg">and this is the date to the bottom Uploaded Auguts 4, 2020</div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-base font-extralight">25 June 2022</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Case 2: Without Text

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="justify-betwen flex w-full items-center bg-white">
  <div class="ml-auto">
    <img class="xs:w-16 float-left mr-2 ml-2 h-40 w-14 object-cover md:mr-4 md:ml-4 lg:w-32" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.s2014.png" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="mx-8 w-full">
    <div class="text-3xl font-semibold text-red-900">Your Title here</div>
    <div class="my-12">
    </div>

    <div class="text-lg font-extralight">25 June 2022</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> I had use an online image, so you can replace it with your image.

If You want more gap, then simply increase the `my-12` to more.